# OnListIemClick set visibility for each row

Tags: android, listview, row, visibility

I am trying to show a list that when I pressed it in that position I would like to show an image that is gone and to change the typeface of that row. So first I have a xml file with a simple list and then another xml for each row, this one:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icono"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_tick_ingred"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So that is the code to each row, contains an image on the left then a text and finally another image on the right of the row. And the java code:

```
public class TabIngred extends ListActivity {

    ImageView img;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rellenas_ingr); //the list xml layout

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //get data
        if (extras != null) {
            String ingredientesLista[] = extras.getStringArray("ingredientesLista");
            int[] ingredientesImagen=extras.getIntArray("ingredientesImagen");

            setListAdapter (new IngredienteAdapter(this, R.layout.rellenas_ingr_fila, ingredientesLista, ingredientesImagen));
            getListView().setChoiceMode(2);
        }

}

private class IngredienteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private String listaIngred[];
    private int[] listaImagenes;

    public IngredienteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String ingredientesLista[], int[] ingredientesImagen) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, ingredientesLista);
        this.listaIngred = ingredientesLista;
        this.listaImagenes=ingredientesImagen;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // XML de la vista de la fila
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rellenas_ingr_fila, null); //the row for the listview
        }
        String ingred = listaIngred[position];
        int imagen=listaImagenes[position];
        int tickImagen = R.drawable.tick_ingred;//set the image to a tick 


        if (ingred != null) {
            TextView ttitulo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            if (ttitulo != null) {
                ttitulo.setText(ingred);
            }
            ImageView timagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono);
            if (timagen != null) {
                timagen.setImageResource(imagen);
            }
            ImageView ttick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_tick_ingred);
            if (ttick != null) {
                ttick.setImageResource(tickImagen);
                ttick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }   
        return v;
    }
}

 @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

     img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_tick_ingred);
     TextView t= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     if(img.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

         t.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
         img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     }else {
         t.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
         img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     }
 }
}
```

So, I define the getview(), I put the image on gone (thats works), but then the OnlistItemClick() doesn´t work. First when I selected an Item the image isn´t visible and apart for that indefferently the position I pressed the first row is which change the typeface, not the item what I pressed.

Thanks :)

Comment: The image initialize gone (what I want) but when I pressed it doesn´t come visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I define getListView().setChoiceMode(2); and that was because it doesn´t work, I delete the line and works perfect!!

Thanks after all!

Answer (score 0):

in you `onListItemClick` you need to use the `View`

for example:

```
img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_tick_ingred);
 TextView t= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

should be

```
img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_tick_ingred);
 TextView t= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

notice the `v` that is the view of the row clicked

Comment: Hi, I edit above the code, it repair something but not all. if I use the view now it chance the row what I pressed OK! But it is like it understand that the view is gone (loggicaly because i define gone in getview) but when I pressed it doesn´t get visible (the textview get bold). And if I pressed again the text don´t get normal :(

Comment: someone who knows... the image is gone all the time, it doesn´t change when I pressed...